# How can I use sign in array of initial facts with Perl module AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced

Tags: arrays, perl, expert-system

I am trying to use the Perl [`AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced`](https://metacpan.org/module/AI%3a%3aExpertSystem%3a%3aAdvanced) module, and I try to use sign in the array of initial facts. The documentation of this module shows an example:

```
my $ai = AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced->new(
viewer_class => 'terminal',
knowledge_db => $yaml_kdb,
initial_facts => ['I', ['F', '-'], ['G', '+']);
```

but there is something wrong (syntax error). I thing that one `]` missing at the end of code.

**First question**: What is the correct form? When I run the example my terminal shows me a lot of errors.

**Second question**: Can I use a file to stored initial facts?

Thanks for your answers.

**Error log**:

when I use example from documentation:

```
syntax error at mix.pl line 24, near "])"
Global symbol "$ai" requires explicit package name at mix.pl line 26.
Missing right curly or square bracket at mix.pl line 27, at end of line
Execution of mix.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

When I put `]` in its correct place at the end of expression: `initial_facts => ['I', ['F', '-'], ['G', '+']]);`

```
Attribute (initial_facts) does not pass the type constraint because: Validation failed for 'ArrayRef[Str]' with value ARRAY(0x3268038) at C:/Perl64/lib/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm line 1274.
  Moose::Meta::Attribute::verify_against_type_constraint('Moose::Meta::Attribute=HASH(0x3111108)', 'ARRAY(0x3268038)', 'instance', 'AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced=HASH(0x30ef068)') called at C:/Perl64/lib/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm line 1261
  Moose::Meta::Attribute::_coerce_and_verify('Moose::Meta::Attribute=HASH(0x3111108)', 'ARRAY(0x3268038)', 'AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced=HASH(0x30ef068)') called at C:/Perl64/lib/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm line 531
  Moose::Meta::Attribute::initialize_instance_slot('Moose::Meta::Attribute=HASH(0x3111108)', 'Moose::Meta::Instance=HASH(0x32673d8)', 'AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced=HASH(0x30ef068)', 'HASH(0x3118298)') called at C:/Perl64/lib/Class/MOP/Class.pm line 525
  Class::MOP::Class::_construct_instance('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x2eb2418)', 'HASH(0x3118298)') called at C:/Perl64/lib/Class/MOP/Class.pm line 498
  Class::MOP::Class::new_object('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x2eb2418)', 'HASH(0x3118298)') called at C:/Perl64/lib/Moose/Meta/Class.pm line 274
  Moose::Meta::Class::new_object('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x2eb2418)', 'HASH(0x3118298)') called at C:/Perl64/lib/Moose/Object.pm line 28
  Moose::Object::new('AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced', 'viewer_class', 'terminal', 'knowledge_db', 'AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced::KnowledgeDB::YAML=HASH(0x3118478)', 'verbose', 1, 'initial_facts', 'ARRAY(0x3268038)') called at mix.pl line 20
```

Comment: What happens if you add the missing square bracket?

Comment: Could you post the errors please?

Comment: ok i added errors to question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the documentation (and possibly in the module itself).

To set the object up with negative initial facts you need to create the dictionary object first.

```
my $initial_facts_dict = AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced::Dictionary->new(
    stack => [ 'I', ['F', '-'], ['G', '+'] ]);

my $ai = AI::ExpertSystem::Advanced->new(
    viewer_class => 'terminal',
    knowledge_db => $yaml_kdb,
    initial_facts_dict => $initial_facts_dict,
);
```

Comment: I think it is all right but it show me allways: ERROR: No inference was possible.